# Jquery direct users to a specific anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am sure I could search for this if I knew the words to describe what I am looking for.

I have a link that when pressed directs the user to another anchor tag using href="#anchorTagName"... however the link also has an onclick function which makes the div visible that anchorTagName is contained within. As a result the user is never directed to the anchor tag as they fire in the wrong order.

SO how do I make the div visible first and then have the user directed to the anchor tag?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is what you're trying to do....

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#theAnchorTheUserClicks').click(function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();  //prevent the default click action
                  $('#divToShow').show('fast',function() {  //show the div
                    $('#newText').focus();  //set the focus where you want
                  });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id='theAnchorTheUserClicks' href='#newAnchor'>click me</a>
        <div style='display:none' id='divToShow'>
            <a id='newAnchor'>Here I am!</a>
            <input type='text' id='newText'></input>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) to scroll to the div you just made visible.

Most probably, your `onclick` event is preventing the default by retuning false or using event.preventDefault(). Remove that code to allow the default event to happen.

Answer (score 0):

When defining the `click` event on page load, strip the `href` from the link and use the value in your `click` event function to change the page url *after* you have done your script to reveal the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page, maybe it will help you :)
http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/2007/12/04/anchor-based-url-navigation-with-jquery/